# Grabbing a property from an aspx page to an ascx toolbar in VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, toolbar, ascx

I have a web page (aspx)- Purchasing page, with a ascx toolbar - Export Toolbar, that is used to export the data (either .xls or .csv).

I need to grab the Name of the Supplier from the Purchasing page and insert that value into the name of the export file on the ascx toolbar.

On the Purchasing page there is a ddl where the user can select the supplier and a grid that will display all the data. Above the grid there is the tool bar with an export button. I need to be able to grab the text of the dropdown list and utilize that on the ExportToolbar.ascx.vb page so I can take that text and insert it into the name.

I was trying to use a public property get and set method but it was not working. How would I go about grabbing that selected text from the Supplier ddl?

Comment: is the DDL autopostback property set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was this-

On the ascx page I created a public property-

```
 Public Property SupplierSelection As String
         Get
            Return Convert.ToString(ViewState.Item("SupplierSelection"))
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        ViewState.Add("SupplierSelection", value)
    End Set
End Property
```

And then on the aspx page I added this on the load grid event-

```
SupergridToolbar1.SupplierSelection = ddlStrategy.SelectedItem.Text.ToString()
```

I was then able to use the Supplier Selection on the ascx page. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Conventional thinking goes like this: an ascx can be hosted on any aspx page.  So usually it is bad form for an ascx to access properties of its host page.  It is much more proper for the ascx to have a public property and the aspx will push the value into the ascx (as needed).

However, if you really want to go this route, the .Page property (of the ascx) referrs to the host page.  If you cast it to the (stronger) type(name) of the host, you can get to the hosts properties.  Like this:

```
'if your host page is called HostPage (and the class name is the same)
Dim host as HostPage = CType(me.Page, HostPage)
'now refer to the controls on the host (aspx) page
dim example as string
example = host.txtExample.Text
```

Keep in mind, this will cause errors if your ascx is hosted on several pages.

Comment: I tried that initially, but am unsure how to populate the property.-
Code -----
 Public Property SupplierSelection As String
        Get
            Return Convert.ToString(ViewState.Item("SupplierSelection"))
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            ViewState.Add("SupplierSelection", value)
        End Set
    End Property
'And the in order to print it -

Me.ASPxGridViewExporter1.WriteXlsToResponse(String.Format("{0}-{1}", Me.SupplierSelection, Me.Supergrid.Description, _
                            dateprefix), True)

But how would I populate the SupplierName propertty?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an event form this purpose. Define the event on the UserControl like this:

```
Public BeforeExportEventArgs
     Inherits EventArgs

     Public Property FileName As String

End Class

Public Class ToolbarControl
    Inherits UserControl

    Public Event BeforeExport As EventHandler(Of BeforeExportEventArgs)

    Public Sub btnExport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExport.Click
        ' Retrieve File Name
        Dim beforeExpEventArgs As New BeforeExportEventArgs()
        RaiseEvent BeforeExport(Me, beforeExpEventArgs)
        ' Set default filename if not provided by an event handler
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(beforeExpEventArgs.FileName) Then
            beforeExpEventArgs.FileName = "DefaultFileName.csv"
        End If
        ' Export data
End Class
```

Add an event handler to the form that hosts the UserControl:

```
Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits Page

    ' ...

    Public Sub expToolbar_BeforeExport(sender As Object, e As BeforeExportEventArgs) Handles expToolbar.BeforeExport
        e.FileName = ddlSupplier.Text + ".csv"
    End Sub

    ' ...
End Class
```

This way, you avoid tight coupling between the UserControl and the Page. The pages that host the UserControl can set a specific filename, but don't have to.